# Is there a minimum LoopPeriod for for the Extents Merge Policy?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm experimenting with table partitions based on data timestamp, which creates a lot of extents.

I've tried setting `LoopPeriod` to 1 minute, to observe the cluster behavior, but it seems to have a 10 minute minimum.

Is that right? 10 minutes is the minimum LoopPeriod for Extents Merge policy?

Answer (score 0):

I would very strongly recommend that you follow the official documentation, which explicitly says *"This value shouldn't be changed"*, and keep its default value of `01:00:00` (1 hour).

Plus, if you see any other recommendation online that says otherwise, please provide a reference to it in a comment, so it can be fixed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mergepolicy

[image]

Comment: I understand that shouldn't be changed, I'm just experimenting. Right now I'm experimenting with a cluster to better understand the behavior of merge policy with range table partitions. Do you know if the minimum loopPeriod is indeed 10 minutes and if it's related to number of nodes?

Comment: as mentioned in the answer and in the documentation - the `LoopPeriod` should remain with its default value of 1 hour. any dependency you take on other values is non-contractual, and can change without notice. to your other question - its value isn't dependent on the number of nodes.